# How to "really" kill activeObject in Fabric.js with jQuery combination?

Tags: jquery, function, tooltip, kill, fabricjs

I got another problem with my tooltips([Old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845459/fadein-fadeout-wont-fire-correctly-and-repeats-itself-jquery))

**LINK:** [M13 Playground](http://manufaktur13.de/playground/index.html)

When the user deletes the layer in my Fabric.js canvas and reset the variable activeObject

```
canvas.remove(activeObject);
activeObject = null;
```

The .tooltip should show up again but the log file says it is not resettet

So my question is:

How do I really kill the activeObject() in fabric to archieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug - i think if we remove object from canvas we should remove activeObject as well.
I will open a issue on github.

But for now you can do this:

```
canvas.discardActiveObject();
canvas.remove(activeObject);
```

Here is the issue on github: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/962